# How to delete white space between two div element when they display as inline-block

Tags: html, whitespace, css

I want to use `inline-block` to put two div elements side by side (just like `float:left`), but when I open the page in the browser the second div goes to the next line, but when set the center div width to 79% or less. Then it displays in one line, but it seems that there is about 4px space between left and center div, then I set the margin of both div to 0px, result was the same.

If anyone knows about this please suggest me how to solve. Thank in advance.

**Note:** If I user `float` then there is no problem, but I need to use `inline-block`
The code is bellow.

css:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    width: 980px;
}
#container, #left, #center {
    display: inline-block;
}
#left {
    width: 20%;
}
#center {
    width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        left other elements goes here
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        center other elements goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inline-block` leaves `white-space` between elements.

Write elements on same line to avoid white-space.

Change

```
<div id="left">
    left other elements goes here
</div>
<div id="center">
    center other elements goes here
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="left">
    left other elements goes here
</div><div id="center">
    center other elements goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<div id="container"><!--
 --><div id="left">
        left other elements goes here
    </div><!-- 
 --><div id="center">
        center other elements goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

That way you can keep a proper indentation

Comment: Just a side note: You can safely remove the first comment. It does nothing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to remove the white spaces itself

```
<div id="container"><div id="left">left other elements goes here</div><div id="center">center ther elements goes here</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <div id="left">
        left other elements goes here
    </div><div id="center">
        center other elements goes here
    </div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    width: 980px;
}
#container, #left, #center {
    display: inline-block;
}
#left {
    width: 20%;
}
#center {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wow...to many solutions already,

have you tried `display:table`...its simple IE8+ supported and not much css required for it and you get you purpose:

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C8Zad/)

```
#container {
    width: 980px;
    display:table;
}

#left, #center {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inline-block leave white-space (default).

To solve your issue set the end tag of div id="left" directly before the start of the second div.

HERE IS A WORKING [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QW52G/)

Check it out

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        left other elements goes here
    </div><div id="center">
        &nbsp;center other elements goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left:-3px;` on your css code (;